# Automated Accessibilty Testing Tools For Angular SPAs

Tags: angularjs, testing, automation, accessibility

I am wondering if anyone has experience with an automated accessibility testing tool for Angular Single Page Applications (SPA).

I have tried pa11y and it does not seem to be working consistently. Just wondering if there are any other tools out there which are comparable to pa11y in ease of use, but which work with Angular.

Comment: What is 'inconsistent' with pa11y? Angular doesn't differ from any other JS. When PhantomJS has the polyfills and enough time to render the page, it renders the page. The question says nothing on how pa11y is used. Which may mean that it wasn't configured or used properly. If you prefer SO to Google, here's some reading, http://simplyaccessible.com/article/spangular-accessibility/

Comment: Thanks, I have read that article as Google was my first option and I have been searching for automated accessibility tools for weeks. pa11y returns results differently depending on how it is run. If I run it from a javascript it is getting less results than simply running it from the command line.

Comment: You need to make sure that the page was rendered completely before processing its contents. This is a common feature for all browser tests, not just accessibility. In the case of pa11y I guess it is [wait](https://github.com/pa11y/pa11y#wait-number) parameter. Which is 0 by default.

Comment: I added a 10 second wait and still got different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Estus raised a good point in the comment — "does not seem to be working consistently" is not a lot to go on. Regardless, a couple options:

- Take a look at [protractor-accessibility-plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-accessibility-plugin) for NPM which can lean on the Chrome Accessibility Developer Tools or Tenon.
- Related, there is a [tutorial on using Tenon as a Grunt task](http://blog.tenon.io/tutorial-using-tenon-as-a-grunt-task/).

Comment: I had looked at the protractor one and because of the limitations in use, I don't believe we want to implement that solution. I am talking about the number of tests you can make. Tenon isn't an option we want to use either because of the limited number of tests you can run and we don't want to open up our UI to the outside world.

Comment: There is no limit on Tenon when you pay for the product. After all, it's a drop in the bucket compared to the cost of the technical debt and later bug killing you would have to do.

Comment: That unfortunately is a decision which is above my paygrade

Comment: Also, it appears that tenon does not have any option for Section 508 compliance testing.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions. Even though the above solutions will not work for the app I am testing I will accept the answer as tenon is a great solution, just not one our company is willing to use.

Comment: That's kinda tough as 508 suggests an Angular site is a violation since it cannot work with JavaScript turned off. When the 508 refresh comes out, it will likely ditch that and will instead incorporate WCAG 2.0 by reference. I suspect that is why do not see 508 testing in there.

Comment: FWIW, I hope the decision makers reconsider that stance. Good luck.

Comment: I sincerely hope they reconsider as well.

Answer (score 0):

Level Access offers an implementation example of Continuum called 'Continuum for Protractor' that might be a good place to get started. It's available for free at [webaccessibility.com](https://www.webaccessibility.com/). You can use it as a template or as a reference to integrate automated accessibility testing into your existing Protractor tests. [Here's some more information](https://support.ssbbartgroup.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001007726-Access-Continuum-for-Protractor) if you're interested. I also help maintain [Continuum Explorer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/continuum-explorer-commun/bafnegdlhjhdcmakjaankoogodomfbde), which is a free extension for Google Chrome that is framework-agnostic and more interactive if you think that might be a better match for your use case.